# Hadoop command not found for user directory

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata

I m new to hadoop and  trying to view user directory
, but it says command not found.

```
hadoop fs -ls / user
```

Comment: use a space. `hadoop fs -ls /user`

Comment: Thanks but it is not working

Comment: You can try this `hdfs dfs -ls /user`

Comment: No its saying ls: `/user': No such file or directory

Comment: So... Now your check your directory structure with something like `hdfs dfs -ls /` or `hdfs dfs -ls .`

Comment: All other hadoop commands are working well though !  and I m in hadoop root folder which has two sub folder 2.7.2 and hadoop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117655/discussion-between-ruchit31-and-sarvesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the docs.
You must run these commands

```
$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<username>
```

then you can see your contents with `ls`

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -ls /user/<username>
```

or

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -ls .
```